# White Question Mark in Black Diamond

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

We are all familiar with the white question mark inside of a black diamond (�) when there is an encoding issue. Does this 'character' have an offical name? Or is it only referred to as the 'white question mark inside of a black diamond'? What would that name be if it has one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Answer (score 8):

It's called "Replacement Character". See the related [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character).

> U+FFFD �​: "replacement character" used to replace an unknown or
>   unprintable character.

Comment: so, how do we replace the replacement character? i mean what is its ascii code? so i can select it via sql, e.g. char(226) for â

Comment: ASCII goes up to 128, and ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) up to 256, a single byte.  If you wanted to replace this character, you might have to do so by splitting the 2 bytes it into 2 characters of 1 byte each: \xFF and \xFD.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel if the string "Women photographers � New Zealand" is in cell C5, then 
=SUBSTITUTE(C5,MID(C5,SEARCH("New",C5)-3,3),"--") will remove the replacement character to give you "Women photographers -- New Zealand".

Comment: That is not an answer  to the question that was asked.

Comment: Not directly Scott, no. I was answering mars-o's question "how do we replace the replacement character?" with an Excel slant, as the same problem occurs in that environment also. That is how I got here in the first place - before I worked out my own solution. Cheers.